# Alternative for group_concat

Tags: mysql

Is there any alternative to GROUP_CONCAT in mysql.As the maxlength constrint for GROUP_CONCAN is 1024, I need an alternative for that.I cant change the value of GROUP_CONCAN_MAX_LENGTH ,my requirement does not allow it.So I need to concat the strings grouped by ID.

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) is a necessary part of the solution. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this article: [SQL trick: overcoming GROUP_CONCAT limitation in special cases](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-trick-overcoming-group_concat-limitation-in-special-cases)

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(
    CONCAT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(actor_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100, CONCAT(',', last_name), '')
        SEPARATOR ''
      ),
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(actor_id BETWEEN 101 AND 200, CONCAT(',', last_name), '')
        SEPARATOR ''
      )
    ),
    2
  ) AS result
FROM actor
\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
result: AKROYD,AKROYD,ASTAIRE,BAILEY,BARRYMORE,BERGEN,BERRY,BERRY,BERRY,BLOOM,BOLGER,BRIDGES,BRODY,CAGE,CAGE,CHAPLIN,CHASE,COSTNER,CRAWFORD,CRONYN,CRUISE,CRUZ,DAMON,DAVIS,DAY-LEWIS,DEAN,DEGENERES,DENCH,DEPP,DUKAKIS,FAWCETT,GABLE,GOLDBERG,GRANT,GUINESS,GUINESS,HACKMAN,HARRIS,HAWKE,HOFFMAN,HOFFMAN,HOPKINS,HUDSON,HUNT,JOHANSSON,JOHANSSON,JOLIE,JOVOVICH,KEITEL,KILMER,KILMER,KILMER,LOLLOBRIGIDA,MARX,MCCONAUGHEY,MCCONAUGHEY,MCKELLEN,MCQUEEN,MIRANDA,MOSTEL,MOSTEL,NEESON,NEESON,NICHOLSON,OLIVIER,OLIVIER,PALTROW,PALTROW,PECK,PECK,PECK,PENN,PESCI,PHOENIX,PINKETT,PITT,POSEY,PRESLEY,SINATRA,SOBIESKI,STALLONE,STREEP,SWANK,TANDY,TAUTOU,TEMPLE,TORN,TORN,TRACY,VOIGHT,WAHLBERG,WAHLBERG,WAYNE,WILLIAMS,WILLIS,WILLIS,WINSLET,WOOD,WRAY,ZELLWEGER,AKROYD,ALLEN,ALLEN,ALLEN,BACALL,BAILEY,BALE,BALL,BASINGER,BENING,BENING,BERGMAN,BIRCH,BOLGER,BRODY,BULLOCK,CARREY,CHASE,CLOSE,CRAWFORD,CRONYN,CROWE,DAVIS,DAVIS,DEAN,DEE,DEE,DEGENERES,DEGENERES,DENCH,DEPP,DERN,DREYFUSS,DUKAKIS,DUNST,FAWCETT,GARLAND,GARLAND,GARLAND,GIBSON,GOODING,GOODING,GUINESS,HACKMAN,HARRIS,HARRIS,HESTON,HOFFMAN,HOPE,HOPKINS,HOPKINS,HOPPER,HOPPER,HURT,JACKMAN,JACKMAN,JOHANSSON,KEITEL,KEITEL,KILMER,KILMER,LEIGH,MALDEN,MANSFIELD,MCDORMAND,MCKELLEN,MCQUEEN,MONROE,MONROE,NOLTE,NOLTE,NOLTE,NOLTE,PENN,PFEIFFER,REYNOLDS,RYDER,SILVERSTONE,SILVERSTONE,STREEP,SUVARI,TANDY,TEMPLE,TEMPLE,TEMPLE,TOMEI,TORN,TRACY,WALKEN,WEST,WEST,WILLIAMS,WILLIAMS,WILLIS,WILSON,WINSLET,WITHERSPOON,WOOD,ZELLWEGER,ZELLWEGER
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```